# sqlite query does not complete - bad index, or just too much data?

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

I have two tables in SQLITE: `from_original` and `from_binary`. I want to LEFT OUTER JOIN to pull the records in `from_original` that are not present in `from_binary`. The problem is that the query I have written does not complete (I terminated it after about 1 hour). Can anyone help me to understand why?

I have an index defined for each of the fields in my query, but `explain query plan` only mentions one of the indices will be referenced. I am not sure if this is the problem, or if it is just a matter of too much data.

Here is the query I am trying to run:

```
select * from from_original o
left outer join from_binary b
on o.id = b.id
and o.timestamp = b.timestamp
where b.id is null
```

The tables each have about 4 million records:

[image: rowcounts]

I have an index defined on all the `id` and `timestamp` fields (see schema at end of post), but `explain query plan` only indicates that one of the id indices will be used.

[image: explain query plan]

Here is the table schema, including index definitions:

[image: schema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select o.*
from from_original o left outer join
     from_binary b
     on o.id = b.id and o.timestamp = b.timestamp
where b.id is null;
```

(Note:  you do not need the columns from `b` because they should all be `NULL`.)

The best index for this query is a composite index on `from_binary(id, timestamp)`.  You *do* have a lot of data for SQLite, but this might finish in a finite amount of time.

Comment: thanks, that helped (now completed in <30s). I am guessing it was the composite index that helped most? As you say, all of the `b` columns would have been `NULL` anyways, so I do not think pulling them in my query would have been a problem (`select *` vs `select o.*`)?

Comment: @Roberto . . . The composite index should be the primary reason for the improvement in performance.  If you want `NULL` valued `b` columns, you should be able to add them in with a minimal impact on performance.

Comment: It's not that I am interested in seeing the null values. I was just asking for my own understanding and curiosity. Thanks for the explanation.